# How to convert a none RAC db to a RAC db also add a node?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Currently our db Oracle 11g R2 enterprise db, has only 1 node and none RAC, and we are getting a new machine, I would like to RAC the old and new node together. (please do not move me to other site, I want to saty in stack over flow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start with installing the GRID software and configure the cluster. Next install the rdbms software. The installer will detect the cluster and give the choice to install the RAC enabled software on both nodes.

If the software is installed, switch the database to use the new installed RAC enabled ORACLE_HOME. When the database is using the RAC software you can add log groups for the new to create thread. When the logs for the new thread are in place, enable the new thread and start the instance on the new node.

This all assumes that all datafiles are on storage that is shared between both nodes. Of course there are some more details but this is roughly the procedure.

Comment: Our db is huge 1Tb, so prefer not touch the data files... you are right, using em grid would be prefer choice even there are few other choice such using DBCA (which would move data files, so not good for large db), and rconfig (edit CovertToRAC.xml)...

Comment: Only, I did not mean EM - Grid Control - I meant GRID Grid Infrastructure 11gR2 - that contains the clusterware. If the data is on shareable storage there is no need to copy. If there is a need, use the storage features to do it the fastest possible way. The tool of choice would be SQL*plus, or any sql tool that gives access as sysdba.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best aproach is to create a one node cluster using the new machine. Export data from old machine to new machine. Add old machine as a cluster node.

Do the old and new machine have the same specs. I think load balancing will be a problemen when specs are different. I don't think it's supported to have different CPU types. Check HW prerequisits

Comment: our db is huge has 1TB data, so it would tough to import data back to the new RAC...